# como ver todos los valores del array con javascript

Tags: javascript, array, variables

tengo este codigo

```
var t=[]; t[0]="hola"; 
t["despedir"]="adios";
var n=0;
while(t[n]){
alert(t[n]);
n++;
}
```

pero siempre se salta el `t["despedir"]`. ¿Que podria hacer para que no se lo salte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El índice de "hola" es numérico y el de "adios" es cadena, por lo que no puedes acceder al segundo cuando `n` es igual a 1.

Lo que puedes hacer es recorrer con un [for(clave in arreglo)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in) donde, en cada iteración del ciclo, clave es el índice para acceder al elemento.

```js
var t=[]; t[0]="hola"; 
t["despedir"]="adios";
for(let n in t){
    console.log('El índice es: ' + n);
    console.log('El valor es: ' + t[n]);
}
```

Comment: Gracias Triby. me ayudaste bastante